# codeigniter loading views from different folders

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have a form that after submited loads another form (another view from other controller). However, in this second form i don't know why the form validation rules (implemented as in the previous form) are not working and why in the submit i always get page not found. 
Regarding this, i tried to load the pages of the two different models normally in the url. And what happens is that if in the model of the first view if i write in the url:

```
http://localhost/code/index.php/fichas/index
```

he loads this or other page in fichas folder without a problem, if i try the second model (Produtos) like this just to test:

```
http://localhost/code/index.php/produtos/index
```

In this page or other of the produtos folder i always get page not found. Am i missing something important? Why should he be able to load some views i have in some folders inside the "views" and not others?

Thank you!

EDIT WITH SOME CODE:

After index.php i begin with this form (create.php):

```
    <h2>Nova Ficha de Segurança</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('fichas/create') ?>

<label for="cod_produto">Código do Produto:</label>
    <input type="input" name="cod_produto" /><br />

    <label for="nome_produto">Nome do Produto:</label> 
    <input type="input" name="nome_produto" /><br />

    <label for="versao">Versão:</label>
    <input type="input" name="versao" /><br />

    <label for="data_ficha">Data da Ficha:</label>
    <input type="input" name="data_ficha" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Criar Ficha" /> 

</form>
```

function create of fichas.php (controller):

```
public function create()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('versao', 'versao', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
    //$this->load->view('templates/header');    
    $this->load->view('fichas/create');
    //$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
else
{
    $data['teste1']=$this->fichas_model->set_fichas();
    $data['teste'] = $this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();
    $this->load->view('produtos/ponto',$data);
}
}
```

From the previous function i'm redirected to produtos/ponto file:

```
<h2>Identificação do Produto/Identificação da Empresa</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('produtos/ponto') ?>

    <label for="nome_produto">Nome do Produto:</label> 
    <input type="input" name="nome_produto" /><br />

    <label for="descricao_produto">Descrição do Produto:</label>
    <input type="input" name="descricao_produto" /><br />

    <label for="id_ficha">Cod do Produto:</label>
    <input type="input" name="id_ficha" value="<?php echo $teste1['id_ficha'];?>" /><br />

    <h4>Distribuidor</h4>

    <label for="nome_empresa">Nome da Empresa:</label>
    <input type="input" name="nome_empresa" value="<?php echo $teste['nome_empresa'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="morada">Morada:</label>
    <input type="input" name="morada" value="<?php echo $teste['morada'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="cod_postal">Código Postal:</label>
    <input type="input" name="cod_postal" value="<?php echo $teste['cod_postal'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="localidade">Localidade:</label>
    <input type="input" name="localidade" value="<?php echo $teste['localidade'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="input" name="telefone" value="<?php echo $teste['telefone'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="fax">Fax:</label>
    <input type="input" name="fax" value="<?php echo $teste['fax'];?>" /><br />

    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="input" name="email" value="<?php echo $teste['email'];?>" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Seguinte" /> 

</form>
```

Finally, the function ponto() in the produtos controller: THe one where the form validation never works and the load view after submit always get page not found. THat's why i tried to load the views of produtos model alone.

```
    public function ponto()
{


$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

//$data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_produto', 'Nome do Produto', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('morada', 'Morada', 'required');



if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
    //$this->load->view('templates/header');    
    $this->load->view('produtos/ponto');
    //$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
else
{
    $this->produtos_model->set_produtos();
    $this->load->view('produtos/success');
}
}
```

SOLVED:

When i created class Produtos i copied the basics from the Class Fichas so i had in the Class Produto the following:

```
class Fichas extends CI_Controller { ...
```

Thanks a lot for the help anyway, this made me lose a lot of time, but at least now it's solved.

Comment: post some code for what you have done.

Comment: done Rooneyl, please take a look!

Comment: instead of loading the view in the success of the first form, do a redirect('produtos/ponto'); You can pass the data by putting it in flashdata. Let me know if that works.

Comment: i used 
redirect('produtos/ponto');
as you said but i always get page not found :/

Comment: typo in my code => redirect('/produtos/ponto');

Comment: it's solved Rooneyl, please take a look at my post, i edited. It was a basic error :/ Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your second template doesn't seems to have a form start/end tag at all like the first one.

Comment: you are talking about my file ponto.php right?
Could you please be more specific about that? I'm starting with codeigniter and looking at create.php and ponto.php i'm not seeing what you mean by that. Thank you!

Comment: on your produtos/ponto.php file, there is no "<?php echo form_open('fichas/create') ?>" call or <form> tag . without this tag, form submition won't work at all.

Comment: It has. Sorry, i must have missed it in the paste, but if you take a look at the ponto.php i edit and it's there now. Sorry for that.